# Android (RN): How to set lat/long of MapView before render? Getting region update error

Tags: geolocation, react-native, android-mapview

I'm a beginner in RN and i'm having some issues with MapView and geolocalizer. Some one can help?
Its actually 2 issues in one:
I want to know the mobile geolocation and render a map with its lat/long. So, here's what i'm trying:
Using componentWillMount function to get the geolocation with the suggested code: (using this to try to set the state with the coords before render)

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
(position) => {
var initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
this.setState({initialPosition});
},
(error) => alert(error.message),
{enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000} 
);
```

The state initialPosition sets right, but i need to set the latitude and longitude state as well beucase JSON.stringify(position) is a string with many other properties, so how can i do something x = position (of the function) or x = navigator.geolocation return, because when i try to put a var x = initialPosition after this.setState (to treat and get only lat/long from x after), it doesnt receive any value, like if the code didnt work until componentWillMOunt ends. IDK.

Why i'm trying this? Because when i try to rerender the Mapview with the new lat/long from the state initialized i get this error:

Android : Error while updating property 'region' of a view managed by : AIRMap : 
https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/issues/140

Note: i do have the lat/long Delta, as the post suggest(not my post)
How can i do this? Idk if the way i want to do is possible too, any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need latDelta and lonDelta. If it is not running, add more

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

into android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can set current position in componentDidMount().

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
            this.setState({
                region: {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0422,
                }
            });
        },
        (error) => console.log(error.message),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
}
```

In render, use like below:

```
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
    region={this.state.region}/>
```